# If statement to unable and disable

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to add an if statement where by if unable it will insect into user profile and get to the input in the code below,
Have try the below but when I remove yes and leave it empty it show the empty part, but when I add any text it show the other side

Just help me out with how i can arrange it well 
And the code to handle it in admin page

```
<?php if ($yes = $_GET["yes"] == "yes"): ?>


html code to run if condition is empty 

<?php else: ?>

html code to run if condition is yes

<?php endif ?>
```

updated ------

I would like to get 1 or 0 from the user database.

If the number is 1 it will show one part but if is 0 it will show the other part, and also help me with the SQL to insert in the user profile.

Comment: Have you tried `if ( $_GET["yes"] == "yes"):`?

Comment: Your URL would have to be something like website.com?yes=yes. I'd be picking more sensible names than "yes". Why do you expect to run the ELSE condition if the answer is yes???? That is backwards.

Comment: To your update I have a few questions:
Do you already have a user database? What column does this 0 or 1 belong to? Do you already have some code implemented into your project that connects you to the SQL-Database? Which part are you talking about if it's 0 and which part are you talking about if it's 1? 

I am very confused on what kind of answer you're expecting.

Comment: Bro am now to php

Comment: Can u help me on the sql code to insect into user table , and of the one to appear for admin page please brother

Comment: Either give me a **reasonable** thing I'm supposed to help you with or find someone else, ***brother***.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd remove the `$yes` in the first part of the if.

Second of all, there is a `empty()` function you can use to check if the statement is empty and third of all, you can output normal HTML code through PHP by just doing `echo` as you'd do in a terminal.

```php
<?php 
  if($_GET["yes"] == "yes") {
     echo "[your html code to run if condition is yes]";
  }
  elseif($_GET["yes"] == "no"){
     echo "[your html code to run if condition is no]";
  }
  elseif(empty($_GET["yes"])){
     echo "[your html code to run if condition is empty]";
  }
```

Comment: How do you handle the condition where it's Not Yes and Not Empty. I.E it's No.

Comment: Too explicit. You should assume that this badly named 'yes' could contain anything in a URL.

Comment: it only show empty, when i tried the code, if i remove yes and leave it empty yes will show , i want it in a way where by it will get from the user database and set to show or not

Comment: Wait wait wait, what are you getting from the database and how are you getting it from there? And which yes are you removing exactly? It's confusing because both the variable name and the content of the variable could be "yes" in your scenario. Could you please update the code of your question or add it at the bottom? @ChinemeremAlozie

Comment: check again bro

Comment: @THess please bro help out